# For any a either x^2=a, x^2=-a or x^2=-1 has a solution mod p.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

For any $a\quad$ either $x^2=a\quad$, $x^2=-a\quad$ or $x^2=-1\quad$ has a solution modulo p.

I'm not certain if it is true, but I remember seeing something like this before. How can I prove it if it is true?

Comment: Your question and terms are in the heading.

Comment: A useful fact:  the product of two non-residues is a residue.  Thus, if neither $a$ nor $-1$ are squares then $-a$ must be a square.

Comment: "If $p ≡ 3 \pmod 4$ the negative of a residue modulo $p$ is a nonresidue and the negative of a nonresidue is a residue" -[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_residue#Prime_modulus) (This is exactly what you are told to show, so it probably doesn't help much, other than perhaps give another perspective on the problem.)

Comment: Why must the product of 2 nonresidues be a residue?

Comment: This is assuming $p$ is prime, or more generally $a$ and $p$ are relatively prime.  It's not true e.g. for $p = 9$ with $a = 3$.

Answer (score 0):

If $p=2$ the thing is true. If $p$ is odd but $a \equiv 0 \pmod p$ it is true. Finally, for odd prime $p$ and $a$ not divisible by $p,$
$$ (a|p) (-a|p)(-1|p) = (a^2|p) = 1. $$
We have the product of three numbers being $1,$ they cannot all be $-1,$ at least one of them is $+1.$